# Ruby on Rails 6 custom JavaScript file Uncaught ReferenceError: Rellax is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

**Descriptions of issue**
It supposes to add Parallax effect on .rellax elements according to https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax
If you are familiar with Ruby on Rails 6 and Webpacker, would you please explain why rails can't read rellax.js properly and what can I do to make it work? Thank you!

**Terminal**

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-07-15 18:34:48 -0700
   (1.0ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.8ms | Allocations: 2428)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 39.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 13263)
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>

<h4>data-rellax-speed = default</h4>
<section>
  <div class="col">
    <br>With Percentage (0.5) <br><br>
    <div id="21" class="container"><div class="block">#1<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5">#1</span></div></div>
    <div id="22" class="container"><div class="block">#2<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5">#2</span></div></div>
    <div id="23" class="container"><div class="block">#3<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5">#3</span></div></div>
    <div id="24" class="container"><div class="block">#4<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#4</span></div></div>
    <div id="25" class="container"><div class="block">#5<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#5</span></div></div>
    <div id="26" class="container"><div class="block">#6<span class="rellax" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#6</span></div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <br>Without Percentage <br><br>
    <div id="21" class="container"><div class="block">#1<span class="rellax" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#1</span></div></div>
    <div id="22" class="container"><div class="block">#2<span class="rellax" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#2</span></div></div>
    <div id="23" class="container"><div class="block">#3<span class="rellax" style="transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1);">#3</span></div></div>
    <div id="24" class="container"><div class="block">#4<span class="rellax">#4</span></div></div>
    <div id="25" class="container"><div class="block">#5<span class="rellax">#5</span></div></div>
    <div id="26" class="container"><div class="block">#6<span class="rellax">#6</span></div></div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Scripts -->
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'rellax' %>
<script>
    var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
</script>
```

**app/javascript/packs/rellax.js**

```
// ------------------------------------------
// Rellax.js
// Buttery smooth parallax library
// Copyright (c) 2016 Moe Amaya (@moeamaya)
// MIT license
//
// Thanks to Paraxify.js and Jaime Cabllero
// for parallax concepts
// ------------------------------------------

(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals (root is window)
    root.Rellax = factory();
  }
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : global, function () {
  var Rellax = function(el, options){
    "use strict";

    var self = Object.create(Rellax.prototype);

    var posY = 0;
    var screenY = 0;
    var posX = 0;
    var screenX = 0;
    var blocks = [];
    var pause = true;

    // check what requestAnimationFrame to use, and if
    // it's not supported, use the onscroll event
    var loop = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback){ return setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };

    // store the id for later use
    var loopId = null;

    // Test via a getter in the options object to see if the passive property is accessed
    var supportsPassive = false;
    try {
      var opts = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
        get: function() {
          supportsPassive = true;
        }
      });
      window.addEventListener("testPassive", null, opts);
      window.removeEventListener("testPassive", null, opts);
    } catch (e) {}

    // check what cancelAnimation method to use
    var clearLoop = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || clearTimeout;

    // check which transform property to use
    var transformProp = window.transformProp || (function(){
        var testEl = document.createElement('div');
        if (testEl.style.transform === null) {
          var vendors = ['Webkit', 'Moz', 'ms'];
          for (var vendor in vendors) {
            if (testEl.style[ vendors[vendor] + 'Transform' ] !== undefined) {
              return vendors[vendor] + 'Transform';
            }
          }
        }
        return 'transform';
      })();

    // Default Settings
    self.options = {
      speed: -2,
        verticalSpeed: null,
        horizontalSpeed: null,
      breakpoints: [576, 768, 1201],
      center: false,
      wrapper: null,
      relativeToWrapper: false,
      round: true,
      vertical: true,
      horizontal: false,
      verticalScrollAxis: "y",
      horizontalScrollAxis: "x",
      callback: function() {},
    };

    // User defined options (might have more in the future)
    if (options){
      Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key){
        self.options[key] = options[key];
      });
    }

    function validateCustomBreakpoints () {
      if (self.options.breakpoints.length === 3 && Array.isArray(self.options.breakpoints)) {
        var isAscending = true;
        var isNumerical = true;
        var lastVal;
        self.options.breakpoints.forEach(function (i) {
          if (typeof i !== 'number') isNumerical = false;
          if (lastVal !== null) {
            if (i < lastVal) isAscending = false;
          }
          lastVal = i;
        });
        if (isAscending && isNumerical) return;
      }
      // revert defaults if set incorrectly
      self.options.breakpoints = [576, 768, 1201];
      console.warn("Rellax: You must pass an array of 3 numbers in ascending order to the breakpoints option. Defaults reverted");
    }

    if (options && options.breakpoints) {
      validateCustomBreakpoints();
    }

    // By default, rellax class
    if (!el) {
      el = '.rellax';
    }

    // check if el is a className or a node
    var elements = typeof el === 'string' ? document.querySelectorAll(el) : [el];

    // Now query selector
    if (elements.length > 0) {
      self.elems = elements;
    }

    // The elements don't exist
    else {
      console.warn("Rellax: The elements you're trying to select don't exist.");
      return;
    }

    // Has a wrapper and it exists
    if (self.options.wrapper) {
      if (!self.options.wrapper.nodeType) {
        var wrapper = document.querySelector(self.options.wrapper);

        if (wrapper) {
          self.options.wrapper = wrapper;
        } else {
          console.warn("Rellax: The wrapper you're trying to use doesn't exist.");
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    // set a placeholder for the current breakpoint
    var currentBreakpoint;

    // helper to determine current breakpoint
    var getCurrentBreakpoint = function (w) {
      var bp = self.options.breakpoints;
      if (w < bp[0]) return 'xs';
      if (w >= bp[0] && w < bp[1]) return 'sm';
      if (w >= bp[1] && w < bp[2]) return 'md';
      return 'lg';
    };

    // Get and cache initial position of all elements
    var cacheBlocks = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < self.elems.length; i++){
        var block = createBlock(self.elems[i]);
        blocks.push(block);
      }
    };


    // Let's kick this script off
    // Build array for cached element values
    var init = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
        self.elems[i].style.cssText = blocks[i].style;
      }

      blocks = [];

      screenY = window.innerHeight;
      screenX = window.innerWidth;
      currentBreakpoint = getCurrentBreakpoint(screenX);

      setPosition();

      cacheBlocks();

      animate();

      // If paused, unpause and set listener for window resizing events
      if (pause) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', init);
        pause = false;
        // Start the loop
        update();
      }
    };

    // We want to cache the parallax blocks'
    // values: base, top, height, speed
    // el: is dom object, return: el cache values
    var createBlock = function(el) {
      var dataPercentage = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-percentage' );
      var dataSpeed = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-speed' );
      var dataXsSpeed = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-xs-speed' );
      var dataMobileSpeed = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-mobile-speed' );
      var dataTabletSpeed = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-tablet-speed' );
      var dataDesktopSpeed = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-desktop-speed' );
      var dataVerticalSpeed = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-vertical-speed');
      var dataHorizontalSpeed = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-horizontal-speed');
      var dataVericalScrollAxis = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-vertical-scroll-axis');
      var dataHorizontalScrollAxis = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-horizontal-scroll-axis');
      var dataZindex = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-zindex' ) || 0;
      var dataMin = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-min' );
      var dataMax = el.getAttribute( 'data-rellax-max' );
      var dataMinX = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-min-x');
      var dataMaxX = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-max-x');
      var dataMinY = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-min-y');
      var dataMaxY = el.getAttribute('data-rellax-max-y');
      var mapBreakpoints;
      var breakpoints = true;

      if (!dataXsSpeed && !dataMobileSpeed && !dataTabletSpeed && !dataDesktopSpeed) {
        breakpoints = false;
      } else {
        mapBreakpoints = {
          'xs': dataXsSpeed,
          'sm': dataMobileSpeed,
          'md': dataTabletSpeed,
          'lg': dataDesktopSpeed
        };
      }

      // initializing at scrollY = 0 (top of browser), scrollX = 0 (left of browser)
      // ensures elements are positioned based on HTML layout.
      //
      // If the element has the percentage attribute, the posY and posX needs to be
      // the current scroll position's value, so that the elements are still positioned based on HTML layout
      var wrapperPosY = self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper.scrollTop : (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
      // If the option relativeToWrapper is true, use the wrappers offset to top, subtracted from the current page scroll.
      if (self.options.relativeToWrapper) {
        var scrollPosY = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
        wrapperPosY = scrollPosY - self.options.wrapper.offsetTop;
      }
      var posY = self.options.vertical ? ( dataPercentage || self.options.center ? wrapperPosY : 0 ) : 0;
      var posX = self.options.horizontal ? ( dataPercentage || self.options.center ? self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper.scrollLeft : (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) : 0 ) : 0;

      var blockTop = posY + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var blockHeight = el.clientHeight || el.offsetHeight || el.scrollHeight;

      var blockLeft = posX + el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      var blockWidth = el.clientWidth || el.offsetWidth || el.scrollWidth;

      // apparently parallax equation everyone uses
      var percentageY = dataPercentage ? dataPercentage : (posY - blockTop + screenY) / (blockHeight + screenY);
      var percentageX = dataPercentage ? dataPercentage : (posX - blockLeft + screenX) / (blockWidth + screenX);
      if(self.options.center){ percentageX = 0.5; percentageY = 0.5; }

      // Optional individual block speed as data attr, otherwise global speed
      var speed = (breakpoints && mapBreakpoints[currentBreakpoint] !== null) ? Number(mapBreakpoints[currentBreakpoint]) : (dataSpeed ? dataSpeed : self.options.speed);
      var verticalSpeed = dataVerticalSpeed ? dataVerticalSpeed : self.options.verticalSpeed;
      var horizontalSpeed = dataHorizontalSpeed ? dataHorizontalSpeed : self.options.horizontalSpeed;

      // Optional individual block movement axis direction as data attr, otherwise gobal movement direction
      var verticalScrollAxis = dataVericalScrollAxis ? dataVericalScrollAxis : self.options.verticalScrollAxis;
      var horizontalScrollAxis = dataHorizontalScrollAxis ? dataHorizontalScrollAxis : self.options.horizontalScrollAxis;

      var bases = updatePosition(percentageX, percentageY, speed, verticalSpeed, horizontalSpeed);

      // ~~Store non-translate3d transforms~~
      // Store inline styles and extract transforms
      var style = el.style.cssText;
      var transform = '';

      // Check if there's an inline styled transform
      var searchResult = /transform\s*:/i.exec(style);
      if (searchResult) {
        // Get the index of the transform
        var index = searchResult.index;

        // Trim the style to the transform point and get the following semi-colon index
        var trimmedStyle = style.slice(index);
        var delimiter = trimmedStyle.indexOf(';');

        // Remove "transform" string and save the attribute
        if (delimiter) {
          transform = " " + trimmedStyle.slice(11, delimiter).replace(/\s/g,'');
        } else {
          transform = " " + trimmedStyle.slice(11).replace(/\s/g,'');
        }
      }

      return {
        baseX: bases.x,
        baseY: bases.y,
        top: blockTop,
        left: blockLeft,
        height: blockHeight,
        width: blockWidth,
        speed: speed,
        verticalSpeed: verticalSpeed,
        horizontalSpeed: horizontalSpeed,
        verticalScrollAxis: verticalScrollAxis,
        horizontalScrollAxis: horizontalScrollAxis,
        style: style,
        transform: transform,
        zindex: dataZindex,
        min: dataMin,
        max: dataMax,
        minX: dataMinX,
        maxX: dataMaxX,
        minY: dataMinY,
        maxY: dataMaxY
      };
    };

    // set scroll position (posY, posX)
    // side effect method is not ideal, but okay for now
    // returns true if the scroll changed, false if nothing happened
    var setPosition = function() {
      var oldY = posY;
      var oldX = posX;

      posY = self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper.scrollTop : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;
      posX = self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper.scrollLeft : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft || window.pageXOffset;
      // If option relativeToWrapper is true, use relative wrapper value instead.
      if (self.options.relativeToWrapper) {
        var scrollPosY = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;
        posY = scrollPosY - self.options.wrapper.offsetTop;
      }


      if (oldY != posY && self.options.vertical) {
        // scroll changed, return true
        return true;
      }

      if (oldX != posX && self.options.horizontal) {
        // scroll changed, return true
        return true;
      }

      // scroll did not change
      return false;
    };

    // Ahh a pure function, gets new transform value
    // based on scrollPosition and speed
    // Allow for decimal pixel values
    var updatePosition = function(percentageX, percentageY, speed, verticalSpeed, horizontalSpeed) {
      var result = {};
      var valueX = ((horizontalSpeed ? horizontalSpeed : speed) * (100 * (1 - percentageX)));
      var valueY = ((verticalSpeed ? verticalSpeed : speed) * (100 * (1 - percentageY)));

      result.x = self.options.round ? Math.round(valueX) : Math.round(valueX * 100) / 100;
      result.y = self.options.round ? Math.round(valueY) : Math.round(valueY * 100) / 100;

      return result;
    };

    // Remove event listeners and loop again
    var deferredUpdate = function() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', deferredUpdate);
      window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', deferredUpdate);
      (self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper : window).removeEventListener('scroll', deferredUpdate);
      (self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper : document).removeEventListener('touchmove', deferredUpdate);

      // loop again
      loopId = loop(update);
    };

    // Loop
    var update = function() {
      if (setPosition() && pause === false) {
        animate();

        // loop again
        loopId = loop(update);
      } else {
        loopId = null;

        // Don't animate until we get a position updating event
        window.addEventListener('resize', deferredUpdate);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', deferredUpdate);
        (self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper : window).addEventListener('scroll', deferredUpdate, supportsPassive ? { passive: true } : false);
        (self.options.wrapper ? self.options.wrapper : document).addEventListener('touchmove', deferredUpdate, supportsPassive ? { passive: true } : false);
      }
    };

    // Transform3d on parallax element
    var animate = function() {
      var positions;
      for (var i = 0; i < self.elems.length; i++){
        // Determine relevant movement directions
        var verticalScrollAxis = blocks[i].verticalScrollAxis.toLowerCase();
        var horizontalScrollAxis = blocks[i].horizontalScrollAxis.toLowerCase();
        var verticalScrollX = verticalScrollAxis.indexOf("x") != -1 ? posY : 0;
        var verticalScrollY = verticalScrollAxis.indexOf("y") != -1 ? posY : 0;
        var horizontalScrollX = horizontalScrollAxis.indexOf("x") != -1 ? posX : 0;
        var horizontalScrollY = horizontalScrollAxis.indexOf("y") != -1 ? posX : 0;

        var percentageY = ((verticalScrollY + horizontalScrollY - blocks[i].top + screenY) / (blocks[i].height + screenY));
        var percentageX = ((verticalScrollX + horizontalScrollX - blocks[i].left + screenX) / (blocks[i].width + screenX));

        // Subtracting initialize value, so element stays in same spot as HTML
        positions = updatePosition(percentageX, percentageY, blocks[i].speed, blocks[i].verticalSpeed, blocks[i].horizontalSpeed);
        var positionY = positions.y - blocks[i].baseY;
        var positionX = positions.x - blocks[i].baseX;

        // The next two "if" blocks go like this:
        // Check if a limit is defined (first "min", then "max");
        // Check if we need to change the Y or the X
        // (Currently working only if just one of the axes is enabled)
        // Then, check if the new position is inside the allowed limit
        // If so, use new position. If not, set position to limit.

        // Check if a min limit is defined
        if (blocks[i].min !== null) {
          if (self.options.vertical && !self.options.horizontal) {
            positionY = positionY <= blocks[i].min ? blocks[i].min : positionY;
          }
          if (self.options.horizontal && !self.options.vertical) {
            positionX = positionX <= blocks[i].min ? blocks[i].min : positionX;
          }
        }

        // Check if directional min limits are defined
        if (blocks[i].minY != null) {
            positionY = positionY <= blocks[i].minY ? blocks[i].minY : positionY;
        }
        if (blocks[i].minX != null) {
            positionX = positionX <= blocks[i].minX ? blocks[i].minX : positionX;
        }

        // Check if a max limit is defined
        if (blocks[i].max !== null) {
          if (self.options.vertical && !self.options.horizontal) {
            positionY = positionY >= blocks[i].max ? blocks[i].max : positionY;
          }
          if (self.options.horizontal && !self.options.vertical) {
            positionX = positionX >= blocks[i].max ? blocks[i].max : positionX;
          }
        }

        // Check if directional max limits are defined
        if (blocks[i].maxY != null) {
            positionY = positionY >= blocks[i].maxY ? blocks[i].maxY : positionY;
        }
        if (blocks[i].maxX != null) {
            positionX = positionX >= blocks[i].maxX ? blocks[i].maxX : positionX;
        }

        var zindex = blocks[i].zindex;

        // Move that element
        // (Set the new translation and append initial inline transforms.)
        var translate = 'translate3d(' + (self.options.horizontal ? positionX : '0') + 'px,' + (self.options.vertical ? positionY : '0') + 'px,' + zindex + 'px) ' + blocks[i].transform;
        self.elems[i].style[transformProp] = translate;
      }
      self.options.callback(positions);
    };

    self.destroy = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < self.elems.length; i++){
        self.elems[i].style.cssText = blocks[i].style;
      }

      // Remove resize event listener if not pause, and pause
      if (!pause) {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', init);
        pause = true;
      }

      // Clear the animation loop to prevent possible memory leak
      clearLoop(loopId);
      loopId = null;
    };

    // Init
    init();

    // Allow to recalculate the initial values whenever we want
    self.refresh = init;

    return self;
  };
  return Rellax;
}));
```

**Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Rellax is not defined**
[image: Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Rellax is not defined]

Comment: I see you copied the rellax.js file from github, does that mean that you are not looking to install it trough yarn?

Comment: Thanks for your question @IvanGarcia! I did "npm install rellax --save" too. It does the same with "yarn add relax" and loads rellax.js in the node_modules/rellax/ but getting the same error. I thought it's better to put rellax.js inside app/javascript/packs for simplicity sake.

Comment: I see, the reason why I'm asking is because I think you are getting the error because probably Rellax is not loaded when the call to new Relax is made, the usual pattern using webpacker to avoid this is to install the required library to the node_modules folder, load it the application.js pack and wait for turbolinks to load. Although if you are looking for a different approach I think another option you can try is to add an event listener in the window `load` event and then call Relax when that event is fired, if that make sense I can elaborate a detailed answer

Comment: Make sense. I guess Rails loading rellax.js later than index.html.erb for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the package you are trying to import is intended to be included as an AMD or as a node module, without entering in much detail what does that mean is that you should include your module either by using
`import Rellax from 'rellax'` or `let Rellax = require('rellax')`, the thing is that by using this kind of import, your packages are not included in the Window objcet, which is the main object where all the global modules and variables are attached, so if you try to access `Rellax` from outside of the scope where rellax is imported, you are not going to be able to access that object, getting the error message you mentioned:

`Rellax is not defined`

Because is actually not defined in that scope.

TLDR;

So in order to fix the issue, you have to include the library and use that library in the same scope, you can achieve that by creating a new js file within your pack directory for example:

**parallax_init.js**

```
import Rellax from 'rellax'

let rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
```

And then include it in your html template using `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'parallax_init' %>`

**Note:**
As you are now using webpacker to handle the js dependencies, you have to use yarn to install the packages as webpacker works with yarn.

You can get more information about the JS scope stuff in the AMD documentation: https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html and in the webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

I also recommend you to read the webpacker documentation, which has a bit more information than the rails guide for the moment(Until the rails guide gets updates): https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage

Comment: I've replaced app/javascript/packs/rellax.js with app/javascript/packs/parallax_init.js and deleted references on line 42, 43 in index.html and did "$ yarn add rellax". This worked well. Thank you!

Comment: Using the `import Rellax from 'rellax'` option, you'll have to run the following `npm i --save-dev @types/rellax`

Answer (score 0):

You can have two approachs to achieve your goal. Install the library or add manually the js files.

If you want to install the library, use yarn (not npm) for that. `yarn add rellax`. Then just import it in **application.js** by doing: `import 'rellax';` This file is located in `app/javascript/packs`.

If you want to add the files manually, put these js files in a folder called `components` or `plugins` inside `app/javascript`. Then import all js files in **application.js**. Having done this correctly, all js files will be available in your views.

It's highly recommended that you read the [Rails Guide: The Asset Pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to understand how to deal with any kind of assets in rails applications.